# Elephant Ear bulbs still attached to the initial bulb that was planted-is this normal? Should I split them ? How do I do that?

Tags: overwintering, bulbs

Elephant Ear bulbs still attached to the initial bulb that was planted-is this normal?
Should I split them ?
How do I do that?
What is the downside of leaving them as they are ?
Here are some pictures
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

They are vigorous growers under conditions they like ( wet and warm). you probably can't hurt them .I have them pop up in the yard when I am not careful where I throw weeding debris ; containing any parts of elephant ears.